# Jython CLASSPATH with *.jar syntax fails with ImportError?

Tags: java, classpath, jython

I have a jython application that uses some libraries from `org.apache....`

I've noticed that when I set the CLASSPATH=/some/path/`*.jar`, the script fails with an `ImportError`, whereas if i set the CLASSPATH=/some/path/`*`, the script will work fine.

```
unset CLASSPATH
jython /path/to/script.py
```

This fails with an `ImportError: No module named apache`

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars/*.jar
echo $CLASSPATH # shows all the jars in the folder
jython /path/to/script.py
```

This fails with the same ImportError

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars/*
echo $CLASSPATH # shows an identical list of jars as the previous classpath
jython /path/to/script.py
```

This succeeds.

Is there something I'm missing about either the CLASSPATH environment variable or about jython? For regular java, sometimes I will set `-cp /path/to/jars/*.jar` and that works. For regular java, I haven't used the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Edit:

If I diff the `echo $CLASSPATH` for both of the ways I set the classpath, there is no difference

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars/*.jar
echo $CLASSPATH >> first.txt
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars/*
echo $CLASSPATH >> second.txt
diff first.txt second.txt
```

The result of this grep command shows nothing:

```
ls -1 /path/to/jars/ | grep -v \.jar$
```

Comment: What about the `:` separator?  If you have more than one jar, you will not have a valid `CLASSPATH` without it.

Comment: @DavidCharles If I set the `CLASSPATH=/path/to/libs/*`, it works fine even though `echo $CLASSPATH` shows no ':' separator. In addition, this works for a plain java job while setting `-cp /path/to/libs/*` or `*.jar`.

Comment: `CLASSPATH` and `-cp`, although used in the same context, expects 2 different list format. `CLASSPATH` is usually separated with `:` while `-cp` is separated with `IFS`. What could be happening to you is that `CLASSPATH` might have a file in other extension including a directory and probably that's what makes it work. Try comparing the content of `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: @alvits I did a diff on the outputs of `echo $CLASSPATH` for both the `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars/*` and `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars/*.jar` and saw no difference.

Comment: I don't want to blame `diff` nor your keen eyes. But I'm curious to see what `ls -1 /path/to/jars/ | grep -v \.jar$` shows.

Comment: @alvits haha. It shows "total xxx" but no additional files

Comment: @alvits BTW, when I `echo $CLASSPATH` after setting it like `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars/*`, the output shows no `:`, yet the script works fine for some reason.